# WPF - Highlight Textbox Based on Content

Tags: wpf, mvvm

I'm learning WPF/MVVM and I have a combo box that updates several text boxes based on the selected combo box value. What I would like to do is highlight some of the thext boxes if they contain a certain value. The text boxes do not receive focus and are read only. What is the best way to go about something like this using MVVM?

**EDIT:**
Thank you for the idea of using a Trigger. I'm actually trying to set the border color of the text box based on the value of the same text box. Based on the information provided below, this is what my text box looks like, but when the word "Transaction" shows up in the textbox, the border doesn't change. Am I referencing something incorrectly?

```
<TextBox Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="170" Grid.Column="4" Grid.Row="2" Margin="4,2,0,0" IsEnabled="False"  DataContext="{Binding SelectedTDetails}" Text="{Binding CType}" Background="WhiteSmoke" Padding="1,0,0,0" >
    <TextBox.Style>
        <Style TargetType="TextBox">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="Text" Value="Transaction">
                    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="LightGreen" />
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </TextBox.Style>
</TextBox>
```

Comment: Background.   And if they are read only then TextBlock is more efficient.

Comment: Try sending the combo-box values to some variables in your ViewModel, then binding this value to the Background property in your TextBox.

Comment: Use `Triggers` in the `TextBox` that points to the `ComboBox` and highlight it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is a sample using Triggers in TextBox

while using this sample trigger the same by typing item 2 in TextBox or select it from ComboBox

```
<StackPanel>
    <ComboBox x:Name="combo">
        <ComboBoxItem>item 1</ComboBoxItem>
        <ComboBoxItem>item 2</ComboBoxItem>
    </ComboBox>
    <TextBox Text="{Binding SelectedItem.Content,ElementName=combo}">
        <TextBox.Style>
            <Style TargetType="TextBox">
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="Text"
                             Value="item 2">
                        <Setter Property="Background"
                                Value="LightGreen" />
                    </Trigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </TextBox.Style>
    </TextBox>
</StackPanel>
```

in above example the TextBox is bound to ComboBox's Selected Item (just to simulate your app's behavior)

The Trigger in TextBox's style look if the Text property contains item 2 and it changes the Background color of TextBox to simulate the highlight

This is just a basic idea on triggers, you may use your creativity to implement the desired highlight behavior perhaps involving flashing color, animated sizing etc.

Comment: Thanks @pushpraj, I updated my question with an attempt to use a Trigger as you suggested.